# Automating forms to 2 seperate websites

Tags: automation

I am working with clients that fill out a paper form. I then take their information and have to input it into 2 separate web sites. How could I automate this? In theory, the client would fill out a digital form and then a script would send the information to the websites. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains the most efficient solution/answer. However if you cant switch to web forms for clients at least write a script which fills and submits both web forms so you dont do unnecessary work.